# p:confirmDialog severity info not working

Tags: primefaces

I am working with PrimeFaces 5.3 and I have a problem. I have a confirmDialog item and by default the severity set to **alert** (show icon alert and red text), I want to change to **info** but when I set *severity="info"* not working and continue showing the icon alert and red text too. What is wrong in my code.

```
 <div class="DispBlock Responsive100 ui-contenedor-botones-accion">
    <p:commandButton id="btnSave" value="#{msj['tag.btnSave']}" update="@form" styleClass="Fright" 
        action="#{operation.save}" partialSubmit="true" process="@form">

       <p:confirm header="Check operation" message="#{vmsj['tag.text.confirmation.operation']}">
       </p:confirm>
    </p:commandButton>
 </div> 
 <p:confirmDialog severity="info" global="true" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade" id="idAcceptOperation" >        
    <p:commandButton value="Yes" type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-yes" />
    <p:commandButton value="No" type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-no" />
 </p:confirmDialog>
```

Why don't apply severity info? Maybe global="true" overwrite severity?

Regards.

Update with more code.

**Update 2**

I have changed my code and now I use the confirmDialog item with global param set to false:

```
<div class="DispBlock Responsive100 ui-content-button-action">
   <p:commandButton id="btnSave" value="Save" update="@form" styleClass="Fright" 
        partialSubmit="true" process="@form" onclick="PF('opeConDialog').show()" type="button">
   </p:commandButton>      

    <p:confirmDialog global="false" widgetVar="opeConDialog" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade" 
            id="idConOperation" severity="info" header="Confirm the operation" 
            message="This is a test">

        <p:commandButton value="Yes" action="#{opeView.save}" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-yes" 
            oncomplete="PF('opeConDialog').hide()"/>
        <p:commandButton value="No" type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-no" 
            onclick="PF('opeConDialog').hide()"/>
   </p:confirmDialog>
</div>
```

This is the result:

[image]

He is using the ui-confirm-dialog-message class.

Why the text continue printing in red colour?

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I get it. I changed the code and set global to false. Besides override the primefaces css and change the style because I never will show the font text in red color.

My confirmDialog code is:

```
<div class="DispBlock Responsive100 ui-content-button-action">
   <p:commandButton id="btnSave" value="Save" update="@form" styleClass="Fright" 
        partialSubmit="true" process="@form" onclick="PF('opeConDialog').show()" type="button">
   </p:commandButton>      

    <p:confirmDialog global="false" widgetVar="opeConDialog" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade" 
            id="idConOperation" severity="info" header="Confirm the operation" 
            message="This is a test">

        <p:commandButton value="Yes" action="#{opeView.save}" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-yes" 
            oncomplete="PF('opeConDialog').hide()"/>
        <p:commandButton value="No" type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-no" 
            onclick="PF('opeConDialog').hide()"/>
   </p:confirmDialog>
</div>
```

and my css override:

```
.ui-confirm-dialog .ui-dialog-content .ui-confirm-dialog-message{color:#72828B !important;}
```

The result:

[image]

I hope it is useful to somebody.